how to access the original nested list after modifying it in loop?
I am modifying the nested list and adding to an array now when I modify nested list it behaving very strangely, I am missing something very small but don't know what.
class Square {
  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

let square = new Square();
square.value = [0, 0];

let arrayOfValues = [[1,2], [2, 3], [4, 5]];
let resultArray = [];
arrayOfValues.forEach(v => {
  let copy = square;
  while (copy.next !== null) {
    copy = copy.next;
  }
  let nextNode = new Square()
  nextNode.value = v;
  copy.next = nextNode;
  resultArray.push(square);
})

console.log(resultArray) //[{value: [0, 0], next: {value: [1, 2], next: {value: [2, 3], next: {value: [4, 5], next: null}}}},....]


// want to return [{value: [0, 0], next: {value: [1, 2], next: null}}, ....]


let copy = square; does not take a copy – it's a reference.

Ya and in alternate version I tried to copy it like let copy = {... square}  it did the trick but when I tried with more nested array it did not worked

Use this corrected version, I used JSON.stringify():
class Square {
      constructor() {
        this.value = null;
        this.next = null;
      }
    }
    
    let arrayOfValues = [[1,2], [2, 3], [4, 5]];
    let resultArray = [];
    
    arrayOfValues.forEach(v => {
      let newSquare = new Square();
      newSquare.value = [0, 0];
      
      let nextNode = new Square();
      nextNode.value = v;
      newSquare.next = nextNode;
      
      resultArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newSquare)));
    });
    
    console.log(resultArray);


(1) You should explain what you changed, not just "use this". (2) Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) to clone an object is inefficient and error-prone compared to structuredClone.

Actually JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) did the work but I have done use this to copy the node let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(square)) and after make and another reference let x = copy and then get the next of x and push copy to the resultArray so now I am adding at last next of the node (because it meant to be a linked list)

The problem is in this line:
let copy = sqaure

Objects (and inherently arrays) are passed reference in Javascript, so after this line copy and square are both pointing to the same object.
to create a copy you need to initiate a new instance and copy the values. you can create a copy method in the class or simply create a new instance.


class Square {
  constructor(value = null, next = null) {
    this.value = value
    this.next = next
  }

  clone() {
    return new Square(this.value, this.next)
  }
}

let square = new Square([0, 0])

let arrayOfValues = [[1,2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
let resultArray = []

arrayOfValues.forEach(v => {
  let current = square.clone()
  let nextNode = new Square(v)
  square.value = v

  current.next = nextNode
  resultArray.push(current)
})
console.log(resultArray)




But what if I try to add next in {value: [0, 0], next: {value: [1, 1], next: null}} 

@anu I made a few changes, it seems logical to me now. I didn't quite understand your question though
